# Where to find Vulkan C++ specification?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Where I can find C++ specification for Vulkan (same like the official C one on Khornos pages), describing the particular Vulkan api primitives and functions? Does it even exist (I was trying to find it with no success)?

Personaly I am using the C api even with C++ as I already got used to its style and it fits my needs perfectly (verbose, but you see everything), but I have to go through the code written by other people using C++ api. Usually Vulkan C++ api is just some syntactic sugar build upon the C api function calls, but sometimes digging through vulkan.hpp and trying to figure out what is going on is really annoying.

I am aware of this: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "Vulkan C++ specification". There's a header file containing some functions and types that make using Vulkan more C++-friendly. But those are not part of any actual specification.

The mapping from "VulkanHpp" into regular C Vulkan is pretty obvious in most cases and can be deduced just from the nature of the APIs in question. `vk::ImageCreateInfo` means the same thing, with the same fields, as `VkImageCreateInfo` as defined by the Vulkan specification. The C++ wrapper is not trying to confuse users as to how it works.

Comment: Yes, I basically agree, but you need to dig quite a lot to find link for Vulkan-Hpp project on Khronos official page. Without the link for example I was pretty aware that create"XYZ"Unique has something to do with C++ smart pointers, but I wanted to be sure that my assumption is correct, same was with behaviour of creating VkFlag bitmasks. But maybe it is just me and my ability to break up and complicate things - I assume that I would be a good tester :D Thank you anyway for clarification.

Comment: @CJ_Notned You're not alone in finding it obtuse to navigate. It'd be nice to have _some_ form of basic documentation to help it out a bit; even if most of it just links back to the official spec for the calls that they abstract.